# unable to use textblob on EC2 Django Virtualenv : MissingCorpusError at /info/ Looks like you are missing some required data for this feature

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-ec2

I have created a django templatetag that calculates the sentiment of tweets below. Every time I try to access the page I receive a

```
MissingCorpusError at /info/

Looks like you are missing some required data for this feature.

To download the necessary data, simply run

    python -m textblob.download_corpora

or use the NLTK downloader to download the missing data: http://nltk.org/data.html
If this doesn't fix the problem, file an issue at https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues.
```

I tried to run the python command suggested but received that everything from that command was already installed and up to date. I have noticed that this issue is filled on github and is unresolved however the posts have been stagnate for sometime. I also notice if I scroll down in the django error message in my browser I notice.

```
During handling of the above exception ( ********************************************************************** Resource 'tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle' not found. Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource: >>> nltk.download() Searched in: - '/var/www/nltk_data' - '/usr/share/nltk_data' - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data' - '/usr/lib/nltk_data' - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data' - '' **********************************************************************), another exception occurred:
```

To fix this I tried to use import

```
textblob.download_corpora
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```

in my temp_functions.py with still no luck. I also tried to install these functions through the django python shell but received a message that they where already installed. I have tried to run the page on both apache2 and the django runserver command with no luck in either.

```
temp_functions.py
from django import template
from textblob import TextBlob
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
register = template.Library()
import textblob.download_corpora
import nltk


@register.filter
def sent(tweet):
    y = []
    blob = TextBlob(tweet)
    for sentence in blob.sentences:
        x = sentence.sentiment.polarity
        y.append(x)

    return str(y)
```

My views.py function associated with the page

```
def info(request):
"""
Redirect page of after authenticate
"""

test = pd.DataFrame
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(request.session.get('key'), request.session.get('secret'))
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Get username

tweets = tweepy.API(auth)
user_data = api.user_timeline()
#print(formated)
# Get timeline
timeline_list = api.home_timeline()
username = api.me().name
```

and finally my info.html page

```
{% extends "twitter/base.html" %}
{% load temp_functions %}


    {% block content %}
        <div id="container">
            <h3>{{userSpecs}}</h3>

            {% for users in user %}
                <p>{{users.user.name}} : {{users.text}} |{{users.user.created_at}}<p/>
                <p>{{ user.text | sent }}
            {% endfor %}
            <a href="/logout/" title="logout">logout</a>
        </div>

{% endblock %}
```

I can run all the python functionality correctly in the shell with no problems and also initially when I first ran it I recieved the missing corpus error but simply installed textblob.download_corpora with no problems through the means suggested.

Note this problem still exists however I found another python library that works if looking for an alternative : https://github.com/fnielsen/afinn